# How to make a list of dictionaries for unknown number of keys in dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

```
def list(file_name):
    list = []
    with open(str(file_name)+".txt") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            s = line.split("|")
            list.append({key1:s[0], key2:s[1],...})
    return list
```

Now the problem I have is this: I have a few lists of dictionaries to create from different files. Not all files are requiring the same number of keys. And the question is how to make those keys to vary from case to case. If I define a function like this

```
def dictionary(file_name):
    if file_name == "something":
        dictionary = {key1:s[0],...}
```

the problem is that the s (that should be split) is not defined for this function. If any of you guys have any ideas how to solve this, please help. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of keys varies per file, it had better be an argument to the function, just like the filename.  And BTW, using names conflicting with builtin identifiers such as `list` is horrible practice, so, fixing that too:

```
def makelist(filename, keys):
    result = []
    with open('%s.txt' % filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            result.append(dict(zip(keys, line.split('|'))))
    return result
```

or, if one prefers conciseness over spelled-out clarity,

```
def makelist(filename, keys):
    with open('%s.txt' % filename) as f:
        return [dict(zip(keys, line.split('|'))) for line in f]
```

Comment: Thank you too for fast answer and for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

thats what dictionaries are for

```
keys = {
    "file1.txt":["KEYS1","Keys2","Etc"]
}

for i,key in enumerate(keys.get(fname,[])):
    dictionary[key] = s[i]
```

alternatively you could do something like

```
all_keys = ["key1","key2","etc","keyn"]
for line in file:
    data = dict(zip(all_keys,line.split("|")))
```

if they always have the same keys, just a different number of them